# Nested Wildcards to Handle Virtual Items in Sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore, wildcard

TLDR; What is the best or recommended way to work with complex virtual items at multiple levels?

I'm working on something currently that instead of using query string variables to filter properties, I would just like to extend the URL and allow those URLs to filter.
Events:
`~/events/2012/april` or
`~/events/lunches` or
`~/events/6CB27D08-358E-49AA-8107-16A50E963C70`

I currently have a wildcard setup to handle the last case or the year but ran into the snag of a wildcard only handling one level so I'm unable to handle `/events/{0}/{1}` with just one wildcard. Further more, I believe that the common friendly url would end up being `/events/2012/april/<external_id>_<event_name>`

Using wildcards, I would need to put them three layers deep with three different layouts to handle each case from what I know currently

```
Events/
        *
          *
            *
```

Is there a better way or a more recommended way to deal with complex virtual items at multiple levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the correct path here and you are correct in that you would need a wildcard item for each segment of the URL. However, just because a wildcard exists doesn't mean you need to use it. In other words, the `/events/*/*` item would handle the `/events/2012/april` URL.

You may want to look at this blog post http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2011/09/Wildcards-and-Data-Driven-URLs.aspx that leads to the [Wildcard Module](http://trac.sitecore.net/WildcardModule/)

Comment: Still stuck with handling my cases three different times this way. Seems opposite of what an `*` would mean, but I'm sure Sitecore has a reason it's this way.  I really like the Wildcard Module though as the configuration then stays within Sitecore instead of a config file.

Comment: The wildcard module worked for us initially, but just couldn't get it to play nicely with the rest of the navigation controls on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific reason for using the wildcard items?
I think you are better off with URL rewriting if you're are going more than 1 level deep with 
wildcards.

So make only the `/events` item and rewrite `/events/{0}/{1}` to `/events?year={0}&month={1}`

Comment: I began using wildcard items because my events are not items in the system but are instead items based off of an API to an external store so it was an easy way to give URLs to events.

Comment: Ruud, do you know how to get URL rewriting to work with Sitecore? When the rules are enabled, it just breaks Sitecore pages (I'm assuming because Sitecore is running the request first versus the URL Rewrite module).

Comment: In my experience, the IIS rewrite module is executed before the Sitecore pipelines. (i do have stopProcessing="true" enabled in my rules, but that shouldn't affect Sitecore)